# Arguments of self executing function

Tags: javascript

```
(function (global, undefined) {
  ... some code which doesnt use arguments array
} (this));
```

I often see *module* pattern done in this way.

I really question why there's a second argument `undefined`?
Are these examples buggy or is there a special meaning of `undefined` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`undefined` is a global property that is widely used. In older versions of JavaScript it is possible to change the value of it (for example, to `true`). This generally breaks everything.
By changing its scope to be local to the "module" (i.e. the function), other modules are prevented from interfering with it.

This allows code to safely use `undefined` instead of having to use `global.undefined`.

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Comment: Really answered my question. Thanks.